Markov kernels "close" implies distributions of Markov chains "close"?
Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}, (Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be two independent Markov chains on a finite state space $S$ with probability kernels $(p_X(s,s'))_{s,s'\in S}$ and $(p_Y(s,s'))_{s,s'\in S}$ respectively. Suppose that the probability kernels are "close" in the sense that there exists a rather small $\epsilon\in[0,1[$, s.t.
\begin{equation}
\max_{s,s'\in S} \:|p_X(s,s') - p_Y(s,s')|\:\leq\: \epsilon.
\end{equation}
Now, fix $s_0\in S$ and suppose $X_0 = Y_0 = s_0$ almost surely.
Question: Is it true that for any $s_1,\dots,s_n\in S$ we may find inequality like
\begin{equation}
|\mathbb P(X_1=s_1,\dots,X_n=s_n) - \mathbb P(Y_1=s_1,\dots,Y_n=s_n)|\:\leq\: f_n(\epsilon),
\end{equation}
where $f_n$ is decreasing for every $n$? And does this inequality get better or worse as $n$ increases?
Attempt: This is more of an intuition. In every step of the chain, the difference in probabilities can be at most epsilon and these "errors" cumulate. So I thought $f_n(\epsilon)=n\epsilon$ might work, but I didn't manage to prove this. Moreover, writing out the probabilites explicitly yields for the left-hand side
\begin{align}
|\mathbb P(X_1=s_1,\dots,X_n=s_n) - \mathbb P(Y_1=s_1,\dots,Y_n=s_n)| = \left| \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} p_X(s_i,s_{i+1}) -  \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} p_Y(s_i,s_{i+1})\right|.
\end{align}
However, I don't see how to continue from here.

Not an analytical answer but rather a probabilistic one: a small change in you Markov chain can drastically change the behaviour. Take the symmetric simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ and an asymmetric one with transition probabilities $1/2\pm \epsilon$ for going left or right. No matter the $\epsilon$ the behaviour changes dramatically as it goes from recurrent to transient.

Fix a sequence of states ${s_i}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ in $S$. Regardless of $\epsilon$, you can write \begin{align}&|P[X_1=s_1,...,X_n=s_n]-P[Y_1=s_1,...,Y_n=s_n]| \ &\leq P[X_1=s_1,...,X_n=s_n]+P[Y_1=s_1,...,Y_n=s_n] \quad \forall n \in {1, 2, 3, ...}\end{align} and the right-hand-side is nonincreasing in $n$. If $S$ is uncountable then the right-hand-side can be zero for all $n$. You may be more interested in comparing  $P[X_n=s]$ and $P[Y_n=s]$ for a given $s \in S$ and for $n \in {1, 2, 3, ...}$. It will help to know if $S$ is finite, countably infinite, uncountable?

@Michael: In my case S is finite.
